# flutter error when archiving "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, flutter, archive

I have this error when doing archive for flutter iOS Build, I really don't know what is the solution for it, this is the error that I'm getting

[You Can Find The Error Here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/2XxNMk7o)  https://www.codepile.net/pile/2XxNMk7o

and I can't find any solution for it!!
could you please help me with this, thanks